# Are Iodine tests reliable?

Tags: mashing

I would be interested to know if iodine tests are a reliable way to know that all the starch has been converted to sugar.

For instance, is it a good way to know if after 30mn of mash-in all the sugars have been converted? Is there a risk of false negatives? false positives?

Please note that this question is different from [this one](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/is-the-iodine-test-for-starch-conversion-pointless) because I'm not asking if iodine tests are useful in practice (I do not use it for now and never felt that I had to) but I would rather like to know if they work effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are reliable if you perform them properly.

- You need to be able to see this blue / green hue. It takes some skill to know what's starch and what's just a color of mixing iodine with wort. Worst in dark beers.
- Test tells only about starch in sample. If you don't stir, you can have starch still in the grain or at the bottom.
- Even if you stir, you can have starch trapped in grain. It wouldn't end in your brew, leaving it is safe, but it hampers your efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is very much a risk of false readings.  I know of people who kept mashing for 4-5 hours because the test showed no conversion.  That's pretty much impossible.  As was said from molot [above](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/18707/14231), if you do it right, you can get useful info, but it's all too easy to mess it up.  It also tells you nothing about the types of sugars you have.
I prefer to check conversion, if I do, using the [braukaiser conversion efficiency chart.](http://www.braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Understanding_Efficiency#Measuring_conversion_efficiency)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to braukaiser, the entier page is super useful!

Answer (score 0):

Using Iodine works very well as long as you let the wort settle before taking a test sample. If you take a test sample that has ANY grain in it, the sample will continue to show high starch because of the grain. Make sure and let the wort settle before taking a sample so that you only pick up clear wort with no grain included. That will give you a good test. Usually within an hour or less.